# Setting GCC to be the only checker for Neomake

Tags: plugin-neomake

I'm trying to set up Neomake to only use GCC as a checker, plus some options. Having looked at the documentation, I wrote this:

```
let g:neomake_c_enabled_makers=['gcc']

let g:neomake_gcc_args=[
      \ '-fsyntax-only',
      \ '-std=c99',
      \ '-Wall',
      \ '-Wextra',
      \ '-Wpedantic',
      \ '-fopenmp',
      \ '-I.'
      \ ]
```

However, when I open a `.c` file and try to have it checked, I get no results, even if there are obvious syntactic errors. Did I miss something obvious here?

Comment: do you have sth like `autocmd! BufWritePost * Neomake` somewhere in your config? or do you call Neomake automatically on other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I finally found the answer myself, and figured I'd leave this as documentation for others.

*Problem:* You want to use GCC as your only maker for C files. You set up Neomake and (Neo)vim the 'obvious' way, but it doesn't do any checking.

*Solution:* There's a couple of things involved here. Firstly, you need to ensure that (Neo)vim doesn't decide arbitrarily that `.h` files are C++ (which it does by default):

```
let g:c_syntax_for_h=1
```

Then, disable all makers for C except for GCC:

```
let g:neomake_c_enabled_makers=['gcc']
```

Then, sprinkle in appropriate arguments (the following are examples) to get the most out of your maker:

```
let g:neomake_gcc_args=[
    \ '-fsyntax-only',
    \ '-std=gnu11',
    \ '-Wall',
    \ '-Wextra',
    \ '-fopenmp',
    \ '-I.'
    \ ]
```

Now, you should have proper checking on both `.h` and `.c` files.